# Preload Link using Files Directive in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm currently preloading font files for one webpage on WordPress.

So `https://example.com` not preloaded. `https://example.com/test/` preloaded font file.

This is what I've got in `.htaccess`.

```
<Files "/test/">
Header add Link "</fonts/poppins.woff2>; rel=preload; as=font; type=font/woff2; crossorigin"
</Files>`
```

The link works fine, it's the conditional loading that I'm struggling with. Tried adding wildcards, plus the full URL, etc, but no joy.

Am I right in thinking it's not the syntax, but it needs allowing before it works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the syntax...

The `<Files>` directive matches against *filenames* only (eg. `foo.php`) - when the request maps to physical files on the filesystem. Since this is WordPress, I assume `/test/` is not even a filesystem directory - it's simply a URL-path?

You can use mod_setenvif to set an environment variable when this URL-path is requested and then set the `Header` conditionally based on this environment variable.

This should go *before* the WordPress front-controller, near the top of your `.htaccess` file.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/test/" PRELOAD_FONT
Header add Link "</fonts/poppins.woff2>; rel=preload; as=font; type=font/woff2; crossorigin" env=PRELOAD_FONT
```

The regex `^/test/` matches any URL-path that *starts* `/test/`. If this should *only* match the single URL `/test/` then append an end-of-string anchor to the regex: `^/test/$`.

Note the extra `env=PRELOAD_FONT` argument at the end of the `Header` directive. The header is only set when the `PRELOAD_FONT` environment variable, set by the preceding `SetEnvIf` directive, is also set.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try it out. Much appreciated for the explanation. Can't upvote yet, so not being ignorant. :)

Comment: Just like to add - it works great. I'll update my Server Push / Preload blog post with the information, so cheers.