# HTTP/2 Server Push Crossorigin not Working for Fonts in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http2

Further to my [original question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1007470/preload-link-using-files-directive-in-htaccess), preloading fonts using link headers in .htaccess, I've since been experimenting with HTTP/2 Server Push for more efficient caching.

Server push works as expected for CSS, JS and Fonts, but the fonts aren't used due to the crossorigin attribute missing.

Adding the crossorigin attribute degrades the push to a preload.

Running out of ideas. Help!!!